# Cloud Firestore - how retrieve document infos of nested subcollection?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, web-applications, rest

The firestore db has a structure like this:
collection: users
documents with id an user_id
each document has a sub-collection: games
each sub-collection has documents with id a game_id

My problem is that I can't loop over the first collection (---> for user in ref_users:) even my firestore db is already full with data organized like I said. Can someone help me understanding how can I retrieve the infos of these documents? Thanks a lot.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    ref_users = db.collection(u'users').get()

    games = []
    for user in ref_users:
        print(f'{user.id} => {user.to_dict()}')
        ref_game = db.collection(u'users').document(f'{user.id}').collection(u'games').get()
        for rg in ref_game:
            print(f'{rg.id} => {rg.to_dict()}')
            tmp = rg.to_dict()
            tmp['game_id'] = rg.id
            tmp['user_id'] = user.id
            games.append(tmp)
    return render_template('game_list.html', title='Game list', games=games)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why can't you loop over the documents from the `users` collection?

Answer (score 1):

Implemented this code on my side with some minor changes and its working fine. So I think that you are maybe searching for solution to decrease computational complexity.
I think that `collection_group` might be helpful. Please check general [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and Python [reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/client.html).

I have created code for the same result as the sample (just `index` part). It has one loop less:

```
def index():

    games = []
    ref_game = db.collection_group(u'games').get()
    for rg in ref_game:
        print(f'{rg.id} => {rg.to_dict()}')
        tmp = rg.to_dict()
        tmp['game_id'] = rg.id
        tmp['user_id'] = rg.reference.parent.parent.id
        games.append(tmp)
    return str(games)
```

I would use more sophisticated name for this subcollection like `userGames` or something. This is because of the fact that `collection_group` works on every collection with this name in whole database. If your system with grow, there is a chance that you will use the same name `games` in some other path not related to this logic. Than it will be included to this `collection_group` and may cause unexpected issues.

Comment: thanks a lot, you gave me a lot of help! Actually was working already before, but your code is better organized.